# Finding Domain name with GODADDY

Tags: dns

Finding a name is easy. Just type in the search bar the name your looking for, but I want to use a name like this `jobs.lockdownjobs.com` is this possible with godaddy? I can't seem to find that name.

Comment: search for `lockdownjobs.com`

Comment: I can. But I specifically want jobs.lockdownjobs.com

Comment: The one who owns `lockdownjobs.com` also controls all subdomains

Comment: Oh. So it's a subdomain. I see

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you buy lockdownjobs.com you can setup any subdomain you want for it through the GoDaddy DNS system.

Cheers!